# Ruby coding exercise solution (rubymonk)

Tags: ruby, class, methods, hash, inject

I am working on understanding a Rubymonk coding exercise solution, and am having trouble understanding what is going on in the `cost` method.

For reference, the `menu` is `{:rice => 3, :noodles => 2}` and the purpose of this is to calculate the total cost of orders from the `menu`.

An order example would be:

```
{:rice => 1, :noodles => 1} )
```

The solution I came up with was simpler, at least in my head, but returned a "cannot convert Symbol to an Integer" error which I was unable to rectify through `to_i`.

```
    class Restaurant
  def initialize(menu)
    @menu = menu
  end

  def cost(*orders)
    orders.inject(0) do |total_cost, order|
      total_cost + order.keys.inject(0) {|cost, key| cost + @menu[key]*order[key] }
    end
  end
end
```

Can someone please explain each step in the `cost` method simply?

Comment: Look up spalt operators and look at some example of the inject function in use.

Comment: @hirolau, `s/spalt/splat/`.

Comment: If you are satisfied with any of the answers you should check the one the was most helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I was wondering how I was supposed to indicate that.

Comment: Most everything you need to know about SO procedure and etiquette is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that a `total cost` is being calculated, it appears that `@menu` contains unit prices (as one generally finds, except perhaps at the very best restaurants) and each order contains the number of each menu item that is ordered.  Suppose:

```
@menu = {rice: 0.69, noodles: 0.89}
```

where the values are unit prices and an element of `orders` looks something like this:

```
{rice: 3, noodles: 2}
```

where the values are quantities ordered.  The cost to supply the quantities given by this order would be:

```
(3)(0.69) + (2)(0.89) = 3.95
```

You are to sum this cost over all orders.

First, let's write the method like this,

```
def cost( *orders )
   orders.inject(0) do |total_cost, order|
     total_cost + order.keys.inject(0) do |cost, key|
       cost + order[key] * @menu[key] 
     end
   end
 end
```

to clarify its structure.  `inject` (aka `reduce`) is iterating over `orders` and accumulating a value in the variable `total_cost`.  You can assign `total_cost`an initial value by passing an argument to `inject` (as you have done).  If you don't give `inject` an argument initial value, `total_cost` is set equal to the first evaluated value in the block that follows `inject`.  In this case, you would get the same results if you dropped the arguments to `inject`.

For the first value of `orders` (the block variable `order`), the following number is added to the accumulator `total_cost`:

```
order.keys.inject(0) do |cost, key|
  cost + @menu[key] * order[key]
end
```

To obtain this value, Ruby must perform a side calculation.  Suppose `@menu` and `order` have the values I gave above.

`inject(0)` iterates over `order.keys` (which is `[:rice, :noodles]`), using `cost` as its accumulator.  The block is executed for `:rice` and then for `noodles`:

```
  cost + order[:rice]    * @menu[:rice]    => 0    + 3 * 0.69  # => 2.07 => cost
  cost + order[:noodles] * @menu[:noodles] => 2.07 + 2 * 0.89  # => 3.95 => cost
```

This completes the side calculation, so 3.95 is added to the outer accumulator `total_cost` (which previously equaled zero).  The next element of `orders` is then processed by the outer `inject`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

First, understand how ruby's Enumerable [`inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) works. "[ruby inject and the Mandelbrot set](http://eigenjoy.com/2008/02/22/ruby-inject-and-the-mandelbrot-set/)" is an introductory article on it.

Based on that understanding, we see that this code:

```
order.keys.inject(0) {|cost, key| cost + @menu[key]*order[key] }
```

is simply returning the sum of all values `@menu[key]*order[key]` as `key` iterates over `order.keys` to give the total cost of each order.

Finally, the outer loop `orders.inject(0) do |total_cost, order| ...` loops over the the cost of each order in the `orders` list, to return the total cost of all orders.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the info. The article was a good read and although it didn't all come together for me right away after reading it, I'm now able to grasp and understand what is going on with inject in this scenario. I think part of the problem as a beginner is unintentionally focusing on the variable names too much in these generic exercises as opposed to how the methods actually work resulting in confusion with what's going on...if that made any sense!

Answer (score 0):

The key to the `cost` definition in your post is obviously the `inject` method.  The `inject` method is also callable as `reduce`, which is a more sensible name to many English speakers, because it takes a list and reduces it to a single value.  (Just to confuse things further, in the literature of functional programming, this function is almost always called "fold").

There are lots of examples; consider finding the sum of a list of integers:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].inject(0) {|sum, num| return sum + num}  #=> 15
```

So what's going on here?  The first argument to the block is the running result - the partial sum in this case.  It starts out as whatever you pass as the argument to `inject`, which in the above example is 0.

The block is called once per item in the list, and the current item becomes the second argument. The value returned by the block becomes the running value (first argument) to the next iteration of the block.

So if we expand the above injection into more explicit imperative code, we get something like this:

```
def block(sum, num) 
   return sum + num
end

result = 0
for i in [1,2,3,4,5]
  result = block(result, i)
end
```

Armed with this knowledge, let's tackle `cost`:

```
 def cost(*orders)
   orders.inject(0) do |total_cost, order|
     total_cost + order.keys.inject(0) {|cost, key| cost + @menu[key]*order[key] }
   end
 end
```

First, it's taking advantage of the fact that you can leave off the `return` in Ruby; the value of the last expression in a block is the return value of the block.

Both `inject` calls look a lot like my example above - they're just simple summation loops.
The outer `inject` builds the grand total across all the individual orders, but since those orders are maps rather than numbers, it has to do more work to get the cost of each order before adding them together.  That "more work" is the inner `inject` call.

```
order.keys.inject(0) {|cost, key| cost + @menu[key]*order[key] }
```

Using my expansion above, you can see how this works - it just adds up the result of multiplying each value in the order (the item quantity) times the price of that item (the key) according to the menu.

Incidentally, you could avoid having to look up the keys in the order map inside the block by reducing over the key/value pairs instead of just the values.  You can also take advantage of the fact that if you don't pass in an initial value to `inject`/`reduce`, it defaults to zero:

```
orders.inject { |grand_total, order|
  grand_total + order.inject { |subtotal, line_item|
    item, quantity = line_item
    subtotal + quantity * @menu[item]
  }
}
```